# How can I reset a form in Odoo with one instruction?

Tags: forms, odoo, reset, odoo-8

I would like to reset all the fields of one form with one instruction in Odoo v8. Is that possible? If not, I will have to reset each field one by one and that is not very clean code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign to all fields (except MAGIC_COLUMNS) the values of  the empty model.

```
from openerp import models

# ... other code

    @api.multi
    def reset(self):
        empty_obj = self.env[self._name]

        for key, value in self._fields.iteritems():
            if value.name not in models.MAGIC_COLUMNS:
                setattr(self, key, getattr(empty_obj, key))
```

Comment: This was very helpful, however I noticed that this does not take default values into consideration. For example, if I have a boolean field with a default of True, the result of this rest function will set this boolean to False. 

I wonder if there is any generalization of this that may take defaults into consideration.